# Transition animiation that shows parts of both pages at the same time?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, animation, windows-phone

In my Phone 7 app, I'm currently using the Silverlight Toolkit's transition service to implement transition animations when the user navigates between pages. It's working. But I don't like these animations because they always consist of two phases: the first phase shows an animation between the current page and the background, and the second one an animation between the background and the next page. It seems that most Phone 7 applications have this kind of animations.

What I would like to have instead is a direct animation from one page to another so that during the animation parts of both pages are visible. For a slide animation for example, the old page would move to the left and directly reveal the new page underneath. During the animation, the screen is split: the left part show less and less of the old page while the right part shows more and more of the new page.

How can I achieve that? Is a Silverlight storyboard able to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I did similar research for calendar control and ended with the next solution:

- before navigating to the other month, copy current control content
  into underlying rectangle (render it to image and use as ImageBrush
  to fill rectangle);
- set current control content Opacity to 0 so that only underlying rectangle is visible;
- create new control content (while it is still with opacity = 0);
- start animation. Animation is performed for underlying rectangle and control content opacities and for their RenderTransforms.
- when animation completes, clear underlying rectangle Fill property.

It's the idea. All storyboards can be defined in xaml, but animation handling requires some code.
I'm not sure whether it is applicable to your case, maybe you need something like Book control.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is a promising approach. However, I don't quite see how it fits into a page to page navigation. It seems to be an animation within a page or control.